# Debian 10 guest freezing on ESXi 6.5

Tags: debian, vmware-esxi, freeze

I have an ESXi 6.5.

Windows and CentOS guests are running fine but my 3 Debian guests freeze after a moment (4 days to 1 week).

Nothing responding, i need to reboot the guest.
The logs files of the guest show no error.

I don't know where to look for and what to do.
An idea ?

Thanks

Comment: When it has frozen, check the VM console for any clues.

Comment: There is nothing on the VM console and it say that the guest not responding. The memory, processor, etc. are at zero.